# Laravel Migration, checking hasColumn but getting Column Exists MySQL Error

Tags: php, mysql, migration, laravel-5.1

I am attempting to create a Migration, adding a column to an existing table.

The up() method doing the initial create for the table looks like this:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('lead_assignments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('version');
            $table->integer('reactor_track_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('lead_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('agent_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('lead_stage_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('managed_by_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('side_of_deal_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('coordinator_id')->unsigned();
            $table->decimal('referral_fee', 15, 2);
            $table->timestamp('response_ts');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();

            $table->foreign('lead_id')->references('id')->on('leads');
            $table->foreign('agent_id')->references('id')->on('agents');
            $table->foreign('lead_stage_id')->references('id')->on('lead_stages');
            $table->foreign('managed_by_id')->references('id')->on('managed_bys');
            $table->foreign('side_of_deal_id')->references('id')->on('side_of_deal');
            $table->foreign('coordinator_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }
```

My Alter up() method looks like this:

```
   public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('lead_assignments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            if (!Schema::hasColumn('lead_assignments', 'property_type_id')) {
                $table->integer('property_type_id')->unsigned();

                $table->foreign('property_type_id')
                    ->references('id')
                    ->on('property_types');
            }
            if (!Schema::hasColumn('lead_assignments', 'referral_fee_expiration')) {
                $table->date('referral_fee_expiration')->nullable();
            }

           $table->dropForeign('lead_assignments_side_of_deal_id_foreign');
        });
        Schema::table('lead_assignments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('side_of_deal_id')->nullable()->change();
        });
    }
```

Here, I am trying to add the property_types column, checking to see if it exists first, and then making it a foreign key after creation.  That works fine. Then I check to see if the referral_fee_expiration column is there, if not, I attempt to create it.

When doing the initial Migration after running 'migrate install', I get this MySQL Error:

> [PDOException]
>   SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name
>   'referral_fee_expiration'

There are no other alters for this table, I'm not sure why it is complaining about the column already being there, when there are no migrations putting it there besides this one, and I'm checking to see if it exists before creation.

Any Advice?

NOTE:

This is starting with a new DB.
I run "php artisan migrate install" and then "php artisan migrate" to produce the error.

Comment: Stupid question, but did you rollback/drop the migration before calling up() again?

Answer (score 0):

If you tried to run the migration earlier and it interrupted with any error then in that case, the statements before the one which caused the error have already been executed. However since the migration returned error before completing in entirety, it will show the status as not migrated or pending.

When you try to rerun the migration it will give you an error for the duplicate column as the statement got executed before the error and the column has already been added to the table  - probably this may be the cause.

In such case even when you rollback the migration, the statements which were already executed before the error was thrown will not be rolled back as the migration itself is not registered with status done.

So you may have to check the MYSQL db with phpMyAdmin or any such tool and if the column in question exists on the table manually drop the column and try running the migration again.

Hope it helps you nail the problem.